# centering x-axis label under grouped bar plots

Tags: r, plot

I have two 3x2 Matrices A, and B :

A:

```
          n2  n3
Part1     1   5
Part2     2   6
Part3     3   7
```

B:

```
          n2  n3   
Part1     5   1 
Part2     6   2   
Part3     7   3
```

and I want to create stacked bar, which I do via:

```
  d1 <- read.csv("A.csv", header=T, dec=".",sep = " ")
  d1 <- subset(d1, select = c(n2, n3))

  d2 <- read.csv("B.csv", header=T, dec=".",sep = " ")
  d2 <- subset(d2, select = c(n2, n3))

  d <- cbind(d1[,1],d2[,1],d1[,2],d2[,2])

  barplot(d, col=c("lawngreen","firebrick","deepskyblue"),
          space=c(0,0,0.2,0), xaxt = "n", yaxt="n",ylim = c(0, 25))

  x_axis_range <- c(2,3)
  x_axis_labels <- c("2", "3")
  axis(1,at = x_axis_range, labels = x_axis_range)

  y_axis_range <- c(0,2,4,6,25) 
  y_axis_labels <- c("0","2","4","6","25") 
  axis(2,at = y_axis_range, labels = y_axis_labels, las=2)
```

and it produces:
[image]

However, I want 2 and 3 to appear centered under each grouped bars. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code that produces the x-axis to

```
x_axis_range <- c(1, 3.2)
x_axis_labels <- c("2", "3")
axis(1,at = x_axis_range, labels = x_axis_labels)
```

[image]

The bars are created with a width of one. In addition, you require to be the space between the second and third bar to be 0.2. Thus, the *left* borders of the bars are placed at 0, 1, 2.2, 3.2. If you want the labels to be placed at the centre of each group, you need therefore to put them at 1 and 3.2, which is what above definition of `x_axis_range` does.

I still left the labels to be 2 and 3, but of course you can change them to whatever you want.